# Download KML or SHP polygon from user input

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

This is a bit "cross-forumy" because it has a GIS element to it, but since it's mainly a HTML / JS question, I thought it best to post here.

I'll be setting up a page with an embedded map (preferably Mapbox but GM API v3 will do just fine in a pinch), where a prospective customer can enter their address, and the map will zoom to that area.

The main aim of the project involves instructing the user to draw a polygon by points, and then click a button sending the polygon to us in KML or SHP format (email, FTP, whatever) so that we can process a quote.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing sounds doable using Mapbox GL JS and a few lines of Javascript. Take a look at these two examples for inspiration:

- https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/mapbox-gl-draw/
- https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/point-from-geocoder-result/

Comment: Thanks Lucas, I will try that out.